# Archives shortcode displaying above widget title

Tags: php, widgets

I'm using the following function to create a shortcode that displays a dropdown for post type archives:

```
// Email Archives Shortcode
function email_archives_shortcode() { ?>
    <select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Month' ) ); ?></option> 
    <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'format' => 'option', 'show_post_count' => 1, 'post_type' => 'emails' ) ); ?>
    </select>
<?php }
add_shortcode('email-archives', 'email_archives_shortcode');
```

It works fine except when I insert the shortcode in a widget, it displays above the widget title instead of below.

Comment: shortcodes should return a value, not echo it

Comment: Thanks @Mark Kaplun but how do I fix it?

Comment: either construct it as a string to be returned, or use `ob_start` and its sibling to capture the output into a string

Comment: If you could edit my code and it works, I can accept it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use output buffering:

```
// Email Archives Shortcode
function email_archives_shortcode() { 
    ob_start(); ?>
    <select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Month' ) ); ?></option> 
    <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'format' => 'option', 'show_post_count' => 1, 'post_type' => 'emails' ) ); ?>
    </select>
    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('email-archives', 'email_archives_shortcode');
```

Or a string

```
function email_archives_shortcode() {
  return sprintf(
    '<select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="">%1$s</option>
    %2$s
    </select>',
    esc_attr( __( 'Select Month' ) ),
    wp_get_archives( array( 
      'type' => 'monthly', 
      'format' => 'option', 
      'show_post_count' => 1, 
      'post_type' => 'emails', 
      echo => false, 
    ) )
  );
}
add_shortcode('email-archives', 'email_archives_shortcode');
```

Comment: I used the first example and works like a charm. Thanks!